Salesaforce data recovery
I have developed a form in salesforce (visualforce page + controller). This form is embedded in an AEM portal managed by an external provider.
It gives me an error so I paste the embedded url into the search engine and I have this case:
If we log in to the AEM portal (provider external to us), it gives us a token. We do the test:
If you paste this: https://icexcrmglobal--uat.sandbox.my.salesforce-sites.com/ContactoEmpresa/apex/FormularioContactoEmpresa?token=1719486191260|-271344752 it shows you the form with the salesforce data filled in (sandbox)
If you paste this: https://icexcrmglobal.my.salesforce-sites.com/ContactoEmpresa?token=1719485167640|-903348339
you get the error. The token is different because the login is different (one in PRODUCTION and another in PRE-PRODUCTION). It is possible that if you try it you will get an error because the token expires.
If we do inspect element in the google chrome tools, we see that a GET call is made here:
https://icexcrmglobal.my.salesforce-sites.com/ContactoEmpresa?token=1719485167640|-903348339
this call receives an unauthorized.

Therefore it is clear that you are trying to recover data from Salesforce, in sandbox it is allowed and in production it is not.

I think this is a key clue, since it seems that the error is not in the code, but rather in access to salesforce data. In sandbox it leaves and in production it doesn't. Could it be due to a recent change in a release? We have to authorize something from prod.

Does the guest user have access to the page and controller in the production environment?
